# Set border color & style in spreadsheet programmatically

Tags: colors, google-apps-script, border, google-sheets

Google Spreadsheet has in the toolbar under the border button also a button to change the color and change the border style.

How can these be accessed within a Google Apps Script?

The `setBorderColor` function which is described for documents seems unavailable for spreadsheets.

Comment: Star this issue, created to make those available in Google Apps Script: [http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2002](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2002)

Comment: Correct link: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2002

Answer (score 26):

The reported issue has been fixed, [as of 12 Jan 2016](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2002#c26). Range now has these methods:

- [setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop-left-bottom-right-vertical-horizontal), as before.
- [setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal, color, style)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop-left-bottom-right-vertical-horizontal-color-style), **NEW!**

Examples are provided in the documentation; here's how to set a dashed red border<sup>*</sup>:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
// Sets borders on the top and bottom, but leaves the left and right unchanged
// Also sets the color to "red", and the border to "DASHED".
cell.setBorder(true, null, true, null, false, false, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED);
```

---

<sup>*</sup>Corrected, as per comment: *the documentation is wrong, it should be SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED/DOTTED/SOLID, not Range. – gotofritz*

Comment: Sadly the example doesn't work, 'Range.BorderStyle.DASHED'  gives a 'Range undefined' error

Comment: Actually discovered the problem - the documentation is wrong, it should be SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED/DOTTED/SOLID, not Range.

Comment: @gotofritz It would be nice to be able to trust the docs, wouldn't it?! Updated answer, thanks.

Comment: How can you get the Border or border style? I check the reference in the documentation. Apparently, this is not possible yet.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the setBorder() properties do not allow us to provide color and style. There is an open issue you can follow [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2002).

Answer (score 4):

You can do a little trick. Copy the formatting in a coloured border cell to where ever you want.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];

var blueBorderRange = source.getRange("B2:D4");

// This copies the formatting in B2:D4 from the source sheet to
// D4:F6 in the second sheet
blueBorderRange.copyFormatToRange(destination, 4, 6, 4, 6);
```