# Changing border colors in GAS (and *not* changing some)

Tags: google-apps-script, colors, google-sheets, border, google-docs

Follow up to this question using Google Apps Script: [Set border color & style in spreadsheet programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900359/set-border-color-style-in-spreadsheet-programmatically)

The format is in this order: .setBorder( top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal, color, style )

According to the documentation,
"true" turns on format
"false" turns off format
"null" leaves it unchanged

My problem: "null" is turning the format off!

I have a very simple script for testing purposes:

```
var right = "red";  
var left = "blue";  
range.setBorder( null, null, null, true, null, null, right, null );  
range.setBorder( null, true, null, null, null, null, left, null );
```

Shouldn't this set the right border red and the left border blue?
The result is only the blue. If I omit the blue line, it'll result in the red.
It seems the only way to get 2+ colors in a single cell is to do .setBorder separately using "null". But "null" is working as "false" and turning off the previous border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetApp.flush() should solve the problem:

```
range.setBorder( null, null, null, true, null, null, right, null );
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
range.setBorder( null, true, null, null, null, null, left, null );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just rephrasing the asked question with the above answer as the following script makes more sense to the first-timers:

```
var rightBorderOn = true;
var leftBorderOn =true;

var rightBorderColor = "red";  
var leftBorderColor = "blue";
  
range.setBorder( null, null, null, rightBorderOn, null, null, rightBorderColor, null );  
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
range.setBorder( null, leftBorderOn, null, null, null, null, leftBorderColor, null );
```

Hope this helps some!