# Google script for Document: border attribute not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to add a border in a google Document image, but I cannot get the result with InlineImage or PositionedImage.

PositionedImage doesn't support setAttributes(), so I will use InlineImage for the example:

Example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19f_vFb6dFov7X8rBZSeThG3xW8ODZaIJuchRl-BPIXk/edit?usp=sharing

The bounded script add the image and try to make it bordered, but it's not working: the border is still absent

```
function test() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.clear();
  
  var par1 = body.appendParagraph("Test");
  
  var bordered = {};
  bordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = "#000000";
  bordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 1;
  
  var image = DriveApp.getFileById("1Z_Tc6LPFTrfl5-BOCkJ6u-Us6jaTAG_-").getBlob();
  par1.appendInlineImage(image);
  par1.setAttributes(bordered);
  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001185/how-to-set-a-border-around-an-image-in-a-doc-using-google-apps-script

Comment: Do you want to put border on your image or the entire page?

Comment: @JoseVasquez Only on the image

Comment: In your situation, is it required to remove the border after the border was added to the image? Namely, do you need the reversibility in your situation?

Comment: No, once added the document will be printed with the border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There's no such feature using Apps Script by now

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute#properties) the attribute **BORDER_COLOR** and **BORDER_WIDTH** are for tables.

```
var bordered = {};
bordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = "#000000";
bordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 1;
```

A community member has opened a [**feature request** in the Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147968327).

### As a workaround use a table and an image inside

This is not the ideal solution but you still can resize the image and table as needed.

```
function test() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.clear();
  
  var par1 = body.appendParagraph("Test");

  var tableBordered = {};
  tableBordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = "#000000";
  tableBordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 3;

  var cellBordered = {};
  cellBordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM] = 0;
  cellBordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_LEFT] = 0;
  cellBordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_RIGHT] = 0;
  cellBordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_TOP] = 3;
  cellBordered[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = "#000000";
  
  var image = DriveApp.getFileById("1Z_Tc6LPFTrfl5-BOCkJ6u-Us6jaTAG_-").getBlob();
  var table = body.appendTable([['']]);
  table.setAttributes(tableBordered);

  var cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(0);
  cell.setAttributes(cellBordered);
  
  var img = cell.appendImage(image);
  img.setWidth(body.getPageWidth() - 3);
}
```

### Reference

[Google Apps Script > Body.appendTable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendtable)

[Google Apps Script > Table.setAttributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setattributesattributes)

[Google Apps Script > Document.Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)

[Google Apps Script > InlineImage.setWidth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#setwidthwidth)

Comment: the result is not very good, but better than nothing