# How do I set the border-weight of an Inline Image in app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How do I set the border-weight of an InlineImage in app script?
The reference pages only show how to change the border width for a cell in table,

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

You can't for now. There's a [feature request for it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147968327?pli=1) and [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001185/how-to-set-a-border-around-an-image-in-a-doc-using-google-apps-script)

**Full Explanation**

Refer to [documentation for InlineImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#setattributesattributes). By right, you can use the `setAttributes(object)` function to set various style attributes. However, looking at the available application [attributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute) for images, `BORDER_WIDTH` applies to tables and not images.