# Customize Tablecell Borders in Google Doc with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm tryna use app script to automatically create receipts, but I can't figure out how to customize Tablecell borders with app script. The "Discount/Premium" row is programmatically added each time a receipt is created, and I can't make the first 2 cells' left and bottom border go away. I don't want to include the row in the template as I don't want to show this row when there is no discount or premium.

Thanks in advance for the help

[Receipt Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkUkz.png)

[image]

Comment: Did you try to google? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900359/set-border-color-style-in-spreadsheet-programmatically Is it the answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set border color & style in spreadsheet programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900359/set-border-color-style-in-spreadsheet-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:

```
function remove_left_bottom_and_inner_borders(range) {
  // top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal
  range.setBorder(null, false, false, null, false, false);
}
```

Elaborated answer is here: [Set border color & style in spreadsheet programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900359/set-border-color-style-in-spreadsheet-programmatically)

Documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBorder(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean)

All you need is to figure out the range for these two cells.